# List Item Validation Failed

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, list-form, validation

I'm trying to use the UPPER formula for a column input, in my case the column name is "Client" and I want the user to enter the client's name as an uppercased string

[image: this is what it shows after entering either a lower or uppercased string and clicking save]

I tried: `=UPPER(Client)`
and `=Client=UPPER(Client)`in the formula box and none worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the below formula

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FIND(UPPER(Title),Title)))
```

[image]

**[Output]**

[image]

---

**Other Workaround,**

- Remove the current validation formula,
- Try to create a new `calculated field` with the below formula

  ```
  =UPPER([the column name])
  ```

Then use the `newly calculated column` as per view purposes like "`All Items, Display`" pages